# Android Studio: App has stopped but no error/ OnClickListener Issue

Tags: android, onclicklistener

As shown in the image, what I would like to happen is that if I press on Dwyane Wade2, it should redirect to a page displaying information about Dwyane Wade2. However, if I do that, it prompts a "App has stopped" and redirects back to my main screen. There are no errors shown so I'm not sure where it went wrong.

[image: screen]

Here's the relevant part.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_content);

        Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();
        String headline = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("HEADLINE");

        TextView txv_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_author);
        txv_author.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TextView target_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_author);
                        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(ArticleContentActivity.this, AuthorActivity.class);
                        launchIntent.putExtra("AUTHOR", target_author.getText());
                        startActivity(launchIntent);
                        return;
                    }
                }

        );

        TextView txv_publisher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_publisher);
        txv_publisher.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TextView target_publisher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_author);
                        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(ArticleContentActivity.this, PublisherActivity.class);
                        launchIntent.putExtra("PUBLISHER", target_publisher.getText());
                        startActivity(launchIntent);
                        return;
                    }
                }

        );

        ArtickelApp app = (ArtickelApp) getApplication();
        ArrayList<article> articleList = app.getArticleList();

        article selectedArticle = null;

        for (int i = 0;i < articleList.size(); i++) {
            String tempHeadline = articleList.get(i).getHeadline();

            if (headline.equals(tempHeadline) == true) {
                selectedArticle = articleList.get(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (selectedArticle != null)
        {
            loadarticleProfile(selectedArticle);
        }
        return;
    }

    private void loadarticleProfile(article articleProfile)
    {
        TextView txv_Headline = (TextView) findViewById(txv_headline);
        TextView txvDet1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_author);
        TextView txvDet2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_content);
        TextView txvDet3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_publisher);

        txv_Headline.setText (articleProfile.getHeadline());
        txvDet1.setText (articleProfile.getAuthor() );
        txvDet2.setText (articleProfile.getContent() );
        txvDet3.setText (articleProfile.getPublisher());
      //  txvDet3.setText (friendProfile.getDescription());

        return;
    }
    }
```

Author Activity page:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_author);

        Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();
        final String author = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("AUTHOR");

        ArtickelApp app = (ArtickelApp) getApplication();
        ArrayList<Author> authorList = app.getAuthorList();

        Author selectedAuthor = null;

        for (int i = 0;i < authorList.size(); i++) {
            String tempAuthor = authorList.get(i).getAuthor();

            if (author.equals(tempAuthor) == true) {
                selectedAuthor = authorList.get(i);
                break;
    }
}
        if (selectedAuthor != null)
        {
            loadProfile(selectedAuthor);
        }
        return;
    }

    private void loadProfile(Author authorProfile)
    {
        TextView txvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_authorname);
        TextView txvDet2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_authorinfo);

        txvName.setText (authorProfile.getAuthor());
        txvDet2.setText (authorProfile.getInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `target_publisher` and `target_author` `TextView` initialization out of `onClick`:

Follow the below code:

```
TextView target_author;
TextView target_publisher;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_content);

        Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();
        String headline = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("HEADLINE");

        TextView txv_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_author);
        target_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_author);
        txv_author.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(ArticleContentActivity.this, AuthorActivity.class);
                        launchIntent.putExtra("AUTHOR", target_author.getText());
                        startActivity(launchIntent);
                    }
                }

        );

        TextView txv_publisher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_publisher);
        target_publisher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txv_author);
        txv_publisher.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(ArticleContentActivity.this, PublisherActivity.class);
                        launchIntent.putExtra("PUBLISHER", target_publisher.getText());
                        startActivity(launchIntent);
                    }
                }

        );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Tried this one, also didn't get errors, however, it still does not do the objective I mentioned.

Comment: Did you add your Publisher and AuthorActivity to the manifest ?

Comment: Already fixed it. There were 2 lines of code on my AuthorActivity.java and PublisherActivity.java preventing the redirection of my app pages. However, I have a new issue brewing.

Comment: Whats the new issue ? Let me see if you may.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Recap: it now does what I mentioned (redirect to the page/activity containing info about the author when the name of the author is clicked). However I'm not sure how to catch the name of author in the author info page. For example, if I clicked on Dwyane Wade, it will redirect to a page containing info about Dwyane Wade. I would want that when I redirect to the Dwyane Wade page, it already displays Dwyane Wade and replaces the temporary textview dedicated to the author name that I placed. Added a new set of code at the end of my post.

Comment: You can do it in various ways. For now, you can put some info as StringExtra for the corresponding author.

Comment: Hi, can you please comment a sample code or integrate the use of StringExtra for catching the author's name. Not sure how to do that part. Was able to catch the headline from the list of article headlines and redirect to the main content of that headline clicked but can't do the same for the author. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your Android Monitor and see which exception is shown in logcat.
I would bet it's a `NullReferenceException` at any point. Some variable/parameter is null and you try to access it.

And, on a more general look: You do not need a `return` statement as the last statement of a method :) It will return anyway.